# How to return keywords for a Facebook event with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am using Facebook's Graph API to pull Events into a website. There is a category field available in the API request (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/event) but for every event I have queried it has been blank. I can't even see a way for users to even add a category when creating an event so it's not surprising they're blank.

Facebook does have a keywords field when you create an event. Is there a way to return this in the Graph API request? I can't find anything in the documentation about it.

Comment: Somehow categories must get added, cause a simple search query for events containing "party" in their name returns several that have category set. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Devent%26q%3Dparty%26fields%3Dcategory&version=v2.11 Values EVENT_DANCE, EVENT_PARTY etc. suggest there's a pre-defined vocabulary, and that it is not free-form. Different search keyword such as "opening" brings up others, such as EVENT_FOOD, EVENT_FILM, FOOD_DRINK. But I don't know of any place where that was actually documented.

Comment: You could file a documentation bug report, and ask them if the could clarify/expand on that. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, i found a similar request: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/624607761061198/.

Looks like keywords aren't available yet, but they may look into adding it in the future.

Comment: Facebook throws "(#200) Permissions error if the access token is not the owner of the event